# Saving Dataframe to text on hdfs generated more than the total count of files

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe r with 165 counts, I save it in text format onto hdfs with the command below:

```
scala> r.rdd.saveAsTextFile("top3_text")
```

here is the list of hdfs files (to save space here, I kept only portion of the list):

```
[paslechoix@gw03 ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls top3_text/*
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         55 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00025
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         57 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00026
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         54 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00027
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         54 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00028
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00029
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00030
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00031
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00032
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00033
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00034
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00035
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00036
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs          0 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00197
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         54 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00198
-rw-r--r--   3 paslechoix hdfs         54 2018-03-21 22:46 top3_text/part-00199
[paslechoix@gw03 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat top3_text/part-00163
[paslechoix@gw03 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat top3_text/part-00162
[paslechoix@gw03 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat top3_text/part-00199
[663,30,139.99,1]
[664,30,139.99,2]
[665,30,139.99,3]
```

This is interesting:
1. What makes the saveAsTextFile generate 200 files?
2. What makes some files are empty while others might contain multiple records?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason!

It is actually decided by the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions setting, the default value is 200: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html

**Reducer number**

> In Shark, default reducer number is 1 and is controlled
>   by the property mapred.reduce.tasks. Spark SQL deprecates this
>   property in favor of spark.sql.shuffle.partitions, whose default value
>   is 200. Users may customize this property via SET:

```
SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10;
```